# SQL Adapter appears not to be filling dataset

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm currently trying to fill a dataset using a database I have. The following code appears not to be filling the dataset at all:

```
    private static DataSet records = new DataSet();
    public static DataSet LoanersData()
    {
        //query string **add more tables as needed**
        string querystring = "SELECT * FROM LoanerItems; SELECT * FROM Customers; SELECT * FROM Jobs";

        //sql connection
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        scsb.DataSource = "LLOYD2\\";
        scsb.InitialCatalog = "LoanersTest";
        scsb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        scsb.ConnectTimeout = 30;

        SqlConnection loanersConnection = new SqlConnection(scsb.ConnectionString);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(querystring, loanersConnection);
        adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "LoanerItems");
        adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Customers");
        adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Jobs");

        adapter.Fill(records);

        return records;
    }
```

And this:

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        records = DataRetreive.LoanersDataSet.LoanersData();
        LoanerItemsTable = records.Tables["LoanerItems"];
        CustomersTable = records.Tables["Customers"];
        LoanerItemsTable = records.Tables["Jobs"];
    }
```

I can't tell for sure if the dataset is filled or not but upon attempting to query one of the datatables like so:

```
            IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from LoanerItems in LoanerItemsTable.AsEnumerable() select LoanerItems;
            foreach (DataRow p in query)
            {
                loanerComboBox1.Items.Add(p.Field<string>("BCPartnNumber"));
            }
```

I get no errors but nothing is added to the combobox. During debug I noticed that it fails to loop through the datarows as nothing is in the datatable.

What I'm trying to do and what I'm doing might be two different things. I'd like to at least clarify that in the table "BCPartnumber is the name of a column. I can provide further code if needed but there's not much else to provide at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to fill the dataset from 3 tables try the three select statements seperately  and change your code as shown in this [article](http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataset/dataset-multiple-tables-oledb.htm)

Let me know if you have questions on this

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you are trying to do is to use Query Analyzer, or SQL Server Management Studio to look at the structure of the LoanerItems table to verify that it has the BCPartnNumber field.

If you had records in the database, your code would throw an exception if there was no BCPartnNumber field in the LoanerItems table.

Comment: It's in the database. Just using the Transact-SQL Editor in visual studio shows me that it's there. I have around 100 records in the database and the column contains no null records.

Comment: Changing it to a column that doesn't exist in the database fails to throw an exception. I assume that means there's no records in the datatable?

Comment: Changing the name of a table in records.Tables fails to throw an exception to. For example `LoanerItemsTable = records.Tables["SomeRandomTable"];` still fails to throw an exception.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error exists somewhere within trying to fill the dataset itself. I'm just unsure what the error is.

Comment: What error are you getting your original post says that you don't get any errors. records.Tables["SomeRandomTable"] should return null, which could cause LoanerItemsTable.AsEnumerable() to throw an ArgumentException. Is this what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'd call this "10 pounds of meat in a 5 pound bag." Your goal is to populate a ComboBox with parts, but your function returns a DataSet of three tables from three queries. Refactor your LoanersData() function into three distinct functions that return a DataTable (instead of a DataSet) for the three sets of data. For example, PartsData() for the part data you want in your ComboBox. Then bind the ComboBox to the results of PartsData():

```
loanerComboBox1.DataSource = PartsData();
```

You'll also have to set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties of the ComboBox, too.